# How do I make my plugin work with specific jquery when there are multiple jquery instances?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

Ok, I thought I better clean this up a bit to make it more clear as to what the issue is. I have a script that may run on websites that may already have jQuery loaded, but possibly the wrong version. So I load the correct version of jQuery and then call the following:

```
myVar = jQuery.noConflict();
```

When I go to code a function that will specifically use my included version of jQuery, how should that be constructed?

```
(function($) {
     $.myPlugin = function(options) {

        // Code here

    }
}(myVar));
```

Does not seem to work. I get an error "TypeError: $ is null"

Answer (score 1):

Load your version of jQuery, initialize your plugin, and then use [`$.noConflict(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to revert to the previous version of jQuery.

Basically you need to make sure that this code gets run after the version of jQuery you need has been loaded:

```
(function($) {
   //...
}(jQuery));
```

The reason for using passing jQuery as a parameter is so that your plugin always uses the right version of jQuery, even if the global `jQuery` and `$` have changed. The local function paramter `$` will always refer to the version of jQuery that was present when the IIFE was first executed.

If you want to check if the available version is compatible with the one you need use `$().jquery` to determine the version number.

Comment: What about events? If the plugin catches browser events will the jQuery used there be the global one or the specific one used when starting the plugin?

Comment: @Nir It will be the one used to create the event listener / the one in the local scope. So it won't be the global one but the specific one.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of jQuery is available with `jQuery().version`

Answer (score 0):

Just check the version of jQuery as the first thing you do. See here:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/

```
if($.fn.jquery != 1.xxx ) { ..... }
```